# Catching a Request with AsynchPostBack?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, request, postback

Is it possible to catch a request when using an asynchpostback?

I'm doing the following. In my masterfile I have 2 buttons for the 2 languages on my site.

```
ScriptManager1.RegisterPostBackControl(linkFR)
ScriptManager1.RegisterPostBackControl(linkNL)
```

I Inherit a class called language in each page. Here I look if there is a request or not. If there is a request look at the controlID of the target and get the correct resourcefile for the website.

```
If Request(PostBackEventTarget) IsNot Nothing Then
  Dim controlID As String = Request(PostBackEventTarget)
```

This works when I let the page refresh, but with asyncpostback no request is sent

Is there another method to catch an asyncpostback?